# How to enable a user to login through FTP?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have installed **vsftp** on Ubuntu 10.10. I want to give the user **FTP login privilage** .

Comment: I updated my answer because my beliefs have changed since the original time I answered this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see an excellent guide below

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3138955&postcount=1

Comment: I think that once VSFTPD is running locally on the system then security can be implemented by not opening the VSFTPD port but instead having clients use Filezilla in FTPS mode to connect to it (via SSH port 22) .

Comment: @djangofan thanks for pointing out FileZilla with SSH, somehow resonated better in my brainz

Comment: That is the long and complicated guide for creating an FTP user. Also, that link is a forum link that could break at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method using ProFTPD:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=429783&postcount=1

But I would recommend the vsftpd method mentioned previously.

But, most importantly, there is no need to do this since, by enabling SSHD on a Ubuntu system, you get access to the FTP subsystem in SSH.   Also, it's way more secure.  So, the question is why would you want to enable any other FTP method besides SSHD??